# Numerical analysis objective question on bisection method.

Tags: numerical-methods, bisection

Let $M$ be the length of the initial interval $[a_0,b_0]$ containing a solution of $f(x)=0$ . Let $\{x_0,x_1,\cdots \}$ represents the successive points generated by the bisection method. Then the minimum number of iterations required to guarantee an approximation to the solution with an accuracy of $\epsilon $ is given by

$1.$ $-2-\frac{log(\frac{\epsilon}{M})}{log(2)}$.

$2.$ $-2+\frac{log(\frac{\epsilon}{M})}{log(2)}$.

$3.$ $-2-\frac{log(\frac{\epsilon}{M})}{log^2(2)}$.

$4.$ $-2-\frac{log(M\epsilon)}{log(2)}$.

Using $$
n\ge \frac{\log{(b_0-a_0)}-\log{\epsilon}}{\log2}
$$ I only got that
$$n\ge \frac{\log{M}-\log{\epsilon}}{\log2}
$$
So
$$
n\ge \frac{\log(\frac{M}{\epsilon})}{\log2}
 =-\frac{\log(\frac{\epsilon}{M})}{\log2}$$

**Now I don’t know from where $-2$ comes.** Please help to find the correct option . Thank you .

Comment: Because before you can "get started" with the process, you need to choose two reference points before you "get going", e.g. $x_0 = a_0, x_1 = b_0, x_2 = \frac{a_0+b_0}{2}$. Then the worst case scenario is if $f(x_0)$ is the same sign as $f(x_1)$, in which case you only start narrowing down where the root is with $x_2$. And if you don't start with $x_0 = a_0, x_1 = b_0$ then the root might not be between $x_0$ and $x_1$, so the bisection method won't work. So you kind of *have to* choose $x_0 = a_0, x_1 = b_0$...

Comment: I have to go out now but I'll try to write an answer when i get back in a few hours (if no one else has).

Comment: @AdamRubinson of sir thank you and waiting for details

Comment: @AdamRubinson if I have to choose $x_0$ or $y_0$ then number of iteration will increase or decrease, I have a doubt again as -2 is added in options .

Answer (score 2):

Ok so in my opinion *it doesn't really matter*, because you already have the answer to your question, which is more about the number of iterations when the ratio $\frac{\varepsilon}{M}$ is small and the $-2$ is not important, probably put in by the lecturer/course director/whoever.

Wikipedia states,

> In mathematics, the bisection method is a root-finding method that
> applies to any continuous functions for which **one knows** two values
> with opposite signs.

So for your question, I think we do know (i.e. we are told) the sign of $f(a_0)$ and $f(b_0)$ because otherwise, $f(a_0), f(b_0), f\left(\frac{a_0+b_0}{2}\right)$, and almost every subsequent midpoint obtained by the bisection method could have the *same sign*, making it impossible to know which interval a root is in.

If $x_0 \in (a_0,b_0)$ or $x_1 \in (a_0,b_0)$, then assuming your bisection method will happen inside $[x_0,x_1],$ the roots could lie outside of $[x_0,x_1]$ but inside $(a_0,b_0),$ so the bisection method might not find the roots, in $(a_0,b_0)$, because it only searches in $[x_0,x_1].$

So I think the following is implicitly assumed by the question:

1. You know the sign of $f(a_0)$ and you know that the sign of $f(b_0)$ is different to the sign of $f(a_0)$: for example you know that $f(a_0)$ is negative and $f(b_0)$ is positive.
2. One of {$x_0, x_1$} equals $a_0$ and the other one of {$x_0, x_1$} equals $b_0.$

This way, the change of sign in the interval $[a_0,b_0] = [x_0,x_1]$ means that the first two points $x_0$ and $x_1$ told us that the root is in the interval $[a_0,b_0]$. So you only start obtaining "new information" that you didn't already know from the 3rd iteration, namely $x_2$, and onwards.

Comment: It's just a matter of how you set up your notation, but probably the way that I would think about it is that bisection generates a sequence of *brackets* and the corresponding sequence of *root approximants* are the midpoints of each bracket. Thus for instance I would probably write $x_0=\frac{a_0+b_0}{2}$. I can see how people might write it the way you described instead, of course.

Comment: In my proposed notation, $n$ is the number of times that the error bound, which is initially $M/2$, must be halved. The number of times that $M/2$ must be halved in order to get to $\epsilon$ is $\log_2((M/2)/\epsilon)=\log_2(M/\epsilon)-1$, so you need $n \geq \log_2(M/\epsilon)-1$. I am actually not sure where $-2$ can possibly come from, because it seems like my notation, in which $a_0$ and $b_0$ are omitted from the sequence of root approximants, should be the form that writes down the lowest value of $n$ (of course the number of bisections that were done is the same regardless).

Comment: Whatever. I don't think it's that important anyway. What's important is the behaviour of $n$ as $\frac{\varepsilon}{M} \to 0.$ (where $n$ is the minimum number of iterations, as in OP's notation).

Comment: I agree it is not important, but I am still curious what notational setup naturally results in this $-2$. Assuming the sequence starts with index zero, the only such "correction terms" I can easily see showing up are $1$ (if $a_0$ and $b_0$ both count) and $-1$ (if neither count).

Comment: @AdamRubinson yes sir I think it is best to think like if $\frac{\epsilon}{M}\to 0$ then $-2$ does not matter , so option $1$ is correct option . Thank you .